# Process a folder of tif files to create searchable PDF files

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, ocr, tesseract, automator

Im working on a workflow to create PDF searchable files plus txt files of recognized text from a bunch of microfilm rolls of newspapers. Each roll has nearly 500 images, like this:

[Microfilm image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBvGC.jpg)

What i'm doing is:

1. Process each roll with ScanTailor advanced, in order to crop images, separate odd and even pages, add margin, and output tiff files for each page, getting this

[File list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fw0i6.png)
[Unique page tif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIRGA.jpg)

2. Then, manually delete of all pages that aren't actually newspaper (like roll start, roll end, advises and other meta-pictures).
3. Then, merge the tif files of one newspaper edition in one file. For example, this specific newspaper has 4 pages per edition. With automator and Imagemagick i wrote a shell service which receive as input a file selection from finder:

   for f in "$@"

   do

   /usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/bin/convert -format tiff -quality 75 -set filename:original '%t' -compress jpeg "$@" -adjoin ~/Pictures/Microfilms/ediciones_%[filename:original].tif

   echo "$f"
   done

Here's where i need help:

- In my ignorance, i had to use -set filename:original '%t' in order to avoid files overwrite, because IM can't merge files (-adjoin) with output filename %escape (e.g. %02d). That's no problem but isn't the ideal.
- How can i cd to the input files parent folder?
- The output folder of ScanTailor has nearly 1000 files, and i need to process 67 folders. So you can imagine selecting each 4 pages of every newspaper edition and do the process manually... So **How can i tell automator to take every 4 (or n) files and execute the convert command with them?**, not all the newspaper has 4 pages per edition, so the best solution is to ask the user how many pages (files) has the newspaper edition. In this case, i can process an entire folder and let the computer working overnight.
- Finally, i process the multi-page tif with Tesseract to output a searchable pdf, and a flat text (.txt). Here i need to add the tesseract process to automator, telling automator to process all the files of merged tif files folder (output of IM process), first with the PDF option and then the TXT option.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The compress jpeg option spoils all your work.
Do not use lossy compression, especially on 1 bit pictures.

Comment: They are not 1bit images, as you can see they are 8bit grayscale

Comment: If you want a clear readable text and a small PDF size, then save after ScanTailor in black and white 1 bit TIFF G4 FAX (or JBIG). Jpeg compression is good for halftone photos, not for newspapers.  If you want an unreadable, blurry text - use JPEG.

Comment: all kind of conversions to 1bit with scantailor or imagemagick are not useful for read the newspaper. Did you see the image?

Answer (score 0):

Ok for who is in the same situation:

I took code from here and there and made an Automator bash script.

I created various folders with the number of editions pages of newspaper inside: folder "2" has all the tiff files that correspond to 2-page newspaper editions, folder "4" has all the tiff files that correspond to the 4-page newspaper editions and so on...

So i open a Finder window and see the files as big icons (thumbnails), listed by 8 columns of files (so i can easily see just in thumbs when a newspaper has more or less than 4 or 8 pages. I move all the tiff files of 2-page newspaper to the folder 2, and o son.

Then i process the folder that contains the numbered folders, with the script (you can download [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mr5EkK82qsQ5uylTYujXd_7dZISOvt74/view?usp=sharing)). I let it also here:

```
for f in "$@"
do 
cd "$@"
if [ -d ./ediciones ]; then
echo "Ya existe la carpeta ediciones. Carpeta ya fue procesada?"
exit 1
else
mkdir ./ediciones
mkdir ./ediciones/ocr
fi


if [ -d ./1 ]; then
cd ./1
/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/bin/convert -format tiff -quality 75 -set filename:original '%t' -compress jpeg +adjoin ../ediciones/edicion_%[filename:original].tif
cd ../
else
echo "No hay periódicos de 1 sola página"
fi

if [ -d ./2 ]; then
cd ./2

arr=(`ls *.tif`)
num=${#arr[*]}
for ((i=0; i<num; i=i+2)); do
j=$((i+1))
k=$((i+2))

/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/bin/convert -format tiff -quality 75 -set filename:original '%t' -compress jpeg ${arr[$i]} ${arr[$j]}  -adjoin ../ediciones/edicion_%[filename:original].tif
done;
cd ../
else
echo "no hay de 2 paginas"
fi

if [ -d ./3 ]; then

cd ./3
arr=(`ls *.tif`)
num=${#arr[*]}
for ((i=0; i<num; i=i+3)); do
j=$((i+1))
k=$((i+2))
l=$((i+3))

/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/bin/convert -format tiff -quality 75 -set filename:original '%t' -compress jpeg ${arr[$i]} ${arr[$j]} ${arr[$k]}  -adjoin ../ediciones/edicion_%[filename:original].tif
done;
cd ../

else
echo "no hay de 3 páginas"
fi

if [ -d ./4 ]; then
cd ./4

arr=(`ls *.tif`)
num=${#arr[*]}
for ((i=0; i<num; i=i+4)); do
j=$((i+1))
k=$((i+2))
l=$((i+3))
m=$((i+4))

/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/bin/convert -format tiff -quality 75 -set filename:original '%t' -compress jpeg ${arr[$i]} ${arr[$j]} ${arr[$k]} ${arr[$l]} -adjoin ../ediciones/edicion_%[filename:original].tif
done;
cd ../
else
echo "no hay de 4 paginas"
fi

if [ -d ./5 ]; then
cd ./5

arr=(`ls *.tif`)
num=${#arr[*]}
for ((i=0; i<num; i=i+5)); do
j=$((i+1))
k=$((i+2))
l=$((i+3))
m=$((i+4))
n=$((i+5))


/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/bin/convert -format tiff -quality 75 -set filename:original '%t' -compress jpeg ${arr[$i]} ${arr[$j]} ${arr[$k]} ${arr[$l]} ${arr[$m]} -adjoin ../ediciones/edicion_%[filename:original].tif
done;
cd ../
else
echo "no hay de 5 paginas"
fi

if [ -d ./6 ]; then
cd ./6

arr=(`ls *.tif`)
num=${#arr[*]}
for ((i=0; i<num; i=i+6)); do
j=$((i+1))
k=$((i+2))
l=$((i+3))
m=$((i+4))
n=$((i+5))
o=$((i+6))


/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/bin/convert -format tiff -quality 75 -set filename:original '%t' -compress jpeg ${arr[$i]} ${arr[$j]} ${arr[$k]} ${arr[$l]} ${arr[$m]} ${arr[$n]} -adjoin ../ediciones/edicion_%[filename:original].tif
done;
cd ../
else
echo "no hay de 6 paginas"
fi

if [ -d ./7 ]; then
cd ./7

arr=(`ls *.tif`)
num=${#arr[*]}
for ((i=0; i<num; i=i+7)); do
j=$((i+1))
k=$((i+2))
l=$((i+3))
m=$((i+4))
n=$((i+5))
o=$((i+6))
p=$((i+7))


/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/bin/convert -format tiff -quality 75 -set filename:original '%t' -compress jpeg ${arr[$i]} ${arr[$j]} ${arr[$k]} ${arr[$l]} ${arr[$m]} ${arr[$n]} ${arr[$o]} -adjoin ../ediciones/edicion_%[filename:original].tif
done;
cd ../
else
echo "no hay de 7 paginas"
fi

if [ -d ./8 ]; then
cd ./8

arr=(`ls *.tif`)
num=${#arr[*]}
for ((i=0; i<num; i=i+8)); do
j=$((i+1))
k=$((i+2))
l=$((i+3))
m=$((i+4))
n=$((i+5))
o=$((i+6))
p=$((i+7))
q=$((i+8))


/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/bin/convert -format tiff -quality 75 -set filename:original '%t' -compress jpeg ${arr[$i]} ${arr[$j]} ${arr[$k]} ${arr[$l]} ${arr[$m]} ${arr[$n]} ${arr[$o]} ${arr[$p]} -adjoin ../ediciones/edicion_%[filename:original].tif
done;
cd ../
else
echo "no hay de 8 paginas"
fi

if [ -d ./12 ]; then
cd ./12

arr=(`ls *.tif`)
num=${#arr[*]}
for ((i=0; i<num; i=i+12)); do
j=$((i+1))
k=$((i+2))
l=$((i+3))
m=$((i+4))
n=$((i+5))
o=$((i+6))
p=$((i+7))
q=$((i+8))
r=$((i+9))
s=$((i+10))
t=$((i+11))
u=$((i+12))


/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/bin/convert -format tiff -quality 75 -set filename:original '%t' -compress jpeg ${arr[$i]} ${arr[$j]} ${arr[$k]} ${arr[$l]} ${arr[$m]} ${arr[$n]} ${arr[$o]} ${arr[$p]}  ${arr[$q]}  ${arr[$r]}  ${arr[$s]}  ${arr[$t]} -adjoin ../ediciones/edicion_%[filename:original].tif
done;
cd ../
else
echo "no hay de 12 paginas"
fi


cd ./ediciones
for i in *.tif ; do 
/usr/local/bin/tesseract -l spa $i ./ocr/$i txt PDF;
done;



cd ./ocr

sed -i '' "s/º/o/g" *.txt


cd ../
cd ../
done;
name=${PWD##*/}
a=1
for i in ./ediciones/ocr/*.pdf; do
  new=$(printf "%03d.pdf" "$a") 
  mv -i -- "$i" "DM_${name}_${new}"
  let a=a+1
done;
for z in ./ediciones/ocr/*.txt; do
  new=$(printf "%03d.txt" "$a") 
  mv -i -- "$z" "DM_${name}_${new}"
  let a=a+1


    echo "$f"
done
```

This code do:

1. Merge tiff files of all editions in one folder that creates (ediciones) using imagemagick, with a reasonably compression.
2. Read the newspapers merged files and create both Searchable PDF and Txt files of the transcription, both files in a subfolder called OCR. This is made with Tesseract and best trainedata files
3. Change all the "º" (always wrote as misrecognized character) with an "o". This is made with sed
4. Rename all the files to fit our archive file name rule. For us is DM_0001_01 (DM for "Diario microfilmado" -microfilmed newspaper-), 0001 is the roll number, and 01+ is the edition inside the roll.

That's it.

I work with Scantailor to produce the files before this, and then i let the pc overnight processing 2 or 3 folders.

Hope it helps to someone like me.